# Why does destroy-service also destroys the machine?

Tags: juju

`juju destroy-service` command destroys the machine if the machine hosts only the service that is being destroyed.

I find it an inconvenience because:

1. it does something unexpected
2. there is an explicit `destroy-machine` command
3. I would like to reuse the machine
4. the data, the logs

Is there a reason for the way it is, and is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to juju but what I do to prevent this is by deploying an [ubuntu](https://jujucharms.com/ubuntu/) charm on that machine and then deploying the service on it.
So, first assign a tag in MAAS UI to that node and deploy ubuntu charm

```
$ juju deploy ubuntu --constraints tags=<tag that you set>
```

A new node will be up with ubuntu charm. Now deploy the service that you want.

```
$ juju deploy <your charm url> --to <newly added machine id>
```

P.S setting a tag to node is optional.